# How to make square of numbers in opposite way?

Tags: c++

I have made a code that makes this kind of output:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6
   7   8   9  10  11  12
  13  14  15  16  17  18
  19  20  21  22  23  24
  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36
  37  38  39  40  41  42
  43  44  45  46  47  48
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   // dimensions:
   int x=6,y=8;
   int sum=0;
   int numery[8][6]={};


   for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            numery[i][j]=++sum;
            if (numery[i][j]<=9) cout << " ";
            cout << numery[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't know how to edit it to get this kind of output:

```
   6   5   4   3   2   1
   7   8   9  10  11  12
  18  17  16  15  14  13
  19  20  21  22  23  24
  30  29  28  27  26  25
  31  32  33  34  35  36
  37  38  39  40  41  42
  43  44  45  46  47  48
```

I can think of making if statement for each i%2==1 that it should go backwards, but I don't know how to make program do such thing. Otherwise it should go normally. So if it find an even row it should go like 7 8 9 10 11 12, whereas if it's i%2==1 it should go like 6 5 4 3 2 1 and so on.
Some suggestions?

Comment: Step 1: find the min and max of the current row; step 2: if the row number is odd, print max->min; otherwise print min->max. Which are you having trouble with?

Comment: Step 0 post precisely the code that you actually tried to run.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be the following (I assume that you do not really need to store the numbers). Notice that `setw()` can be used to print the numbers with fixed width:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // dimensions:
    int x=6,y=8;

    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(3) << ((i%2) ? i*x+j+1 : i*x+x-j) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of the array. It is unnecessary.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int number(int i,int j,int width) { return j+i*width +1 ;}

int main() {
   // dimensions:
   int x=6,y=8;

   for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            auto n = number(i,j,x);
            if (n <= 9) cout << " ";
            cout << n << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This has same output as your code.

Next consider what happens to `j` when you go reverse. You should think that through, the answer is: You replace `j` with `width-j-1`.

```
int number_reverse(int i,int j, int width) { return number(i,width-j-1,width); }
```

Eventually you just need to call the right function in each iteration of the outer loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int number(int i,int j,int width) { return j+i*width +1 ;}

int number_reverse(int i,int j, int width) { return number(i,width-j-1,width); }
int main() {
   // dimensions:
   int x=6,y=8;

   for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            auto n = (i%2) ? number_reverse(i,j,x) : number(i,j,x);
            if (n <= 9) cout << " ";
            cout << n << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in case you DO need to store the numbers in an array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   // dimensions:
   int x=6,y=8;
   int sum=0;
   int numery[y][x];


   for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) 
            numery[i][j]=++sum;
            
         
            
    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            for(int j = x-1; j >= 0; --j)
            {
                if(numery[i][j] < 10)
                {
                    cout << " ";
                }
                cout << numery[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
        for(int j = 0; j < x; j++)
            {
                if(numery[i][j] < 10)
                {
                    cout << " ";
                }
                cout << numery[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;   
        }
    }

   
    return 0;
}
```

you assign the numbers to your array first. then you print the numbers from back-to-front or front-to-back based on if are on an even or odd row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to fill the array in non-linear order, you can fill every second line from right to left: `array[i][x-1-j]=++sum;`.

Another approach is to use one outer loop and two inner loops, noticing that all the rows are of form `a*i + b*j + c`, where b is either +1 or -1. This simplifies to `array[i][j] = 6*i + 6 - j` for even rows and to `array[i][j]=6*i + 1 + j` for the odd rows.

One more option is to have a single inner loop, which will increase or decrease by some amount `d = i % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1;`

```
 for (int j = 0; j<x; j++) { arr[i][j]=sum; sum += d;}
 sum+=6-d;
```

After each row we need to compensate the variable `sum` so that it begins with the correct value for the next index `i+1`.